# simple . validation for php

Tags: php, string, validation

`.` validation for php

Actualy i want to validate with .
like when user enter `abc.dfd` then true otherwise false in `abc` only !!

Some other examples. All are true:

```
adfasf.fdasf
asf.fasdf
adfds.afds
adfs.afdsf
```

while these are false:

```
fsd
fsd
fsd
```

Comment: `if(strpos($string,'.') !==false) { echo 'passed';} else { echo 'failed';}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment suggested, to check for a period or any particular string inside a string, just use `strpos()` and do a sstrict check (!==) check for false.

```
if(strpos($input, '.') !== false) {
    // There is a period
} else {
    // No Period
}
```

Comment: actual i want to make an function for . dude ?bcause i have an textbox when user enter the text on this box if text is like abc.def then true otherwise if abc then false –

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, have you tried this code to see if it works?

Comment: like email function i want to make the for for . string

Comment: So what you actually want is email validation?!?

Comment: u thr i want to ask something

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function:

```
 function validate($str)
 {
   if(preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}/', $str))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**how to use:**

```
 if(validate("abc.acc"))
 { 
  //valid string, do something
 }
 else
 {
   //invalid string
 }
```

or

```
 $string = "acb.ccs.ghd";
 if(validate($string))
 { 
  //valid string, do something
 }
 else
 {
   //invalid string
 }
```

**returns:**

```
$string = "asgasgasgasg"; // false
$string = "asgasga.sgasg"; // true
$string = "asgasga.sgasg.asgasg"; // true
$string = "asgasga."; // false
```

Comment: ya right but how cal this function & wht its name ? function name?

Comment: @harison if it helps , feel free to flag it as the answer.

Comment: @harison do you know how to flag my post as the ANSWER? :D

Comment: @john actualy in this i want to validate number also like when user enter 45.23.56 then also true .....

Comment: the validate() function will do that too... just use if(validate(215.125.2151)) this should work